# Newbie System Monitoring Methodolygy

Tags: c#, .net, class, service, monitoring

I'm writing an agent to monitor and collect various Windows system settings/information using a Windows service written in C# (.NET).
The main service reads from a config file at start up and stores in a list all the tests it must run. A timer then runs the individual methods at the appropriate frequency.
I have created a class library containing individual classes for checking services, regkeys, getting system information etc. The methods in the main service use the methods in the class library to get their information before writing the data out to files and uploading to the main server. Most of the methods in the classes are static (although some are not).
Baring in mind that these methods will be called repeatedly on set frequencies throughout the day is making them static a good or bad idea.
The memory usage is stable but a bit higher than I expected at 25-30MB.
Can anyone see any massive flaw in the way I've done this?
[image: Example]

My WriteToFile and WriteToLog methods are both static void and both create and dispose of a StreamWriter when they are called.
I wondered whether that makes sense or I should do it differently (like creating one StreamWriter at service start up and passing that to the WriteTo methods instead).

Something else I don't understand is that I load a list of checks to run from a text file, the text file is only 3KB in size but it takes an extra 7MB of memory compared with the text file was blank.

Answer (score 0):

> Baring in mind that these methods will be called repeatedly on set frequencies throughout the day is making them static a good or bad idea.

Making a method static doesn't give you dramatically performance boost.

When you design a system you should ask yourself: "How do I test it?".

It is hard to test a system that is based on static classes, you can't easily isolate things to test independently (you have to use [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/) for this purpose).

It also hard to maintain system that contains core logic in a static class, because you can't limit its scope.

> The memory usage is stable but a bit higher than I expected at 25-30MB.

If your program will be running on a desktop platform, then don't worry, 30MB is nothing to a modern desktop computer.